# Varying measurements from measuring tool and using the overlay panel to display the length of a side

Tags: measurement

[image]

As you can see I'm getting too VERY different measurements (24.1397mm and 222mm) on the same side, the 222 is measured by the "edge length" measurement overlay and the 24~ is from the measuring tool, why are they different and which one should I trust?

Comment: Hello, Fish, I think it's fair to call this a duplicate.. as the linked answers suggest, one of the measurements is in World coordinates, the other in Object coordinates, When you scale in Object Mode, the coordinates are scaled along with the object, so object-space lengths are invariant under that operation.